# It sometimes reverse when I turn a string into a set

Tags: python, set

The string is:
`x = 'ABBA'`

whenever I use this code:
`x = 'ABBA' x = ''.join(set(x)) print(x)`

It results in:
`BA`
but I want it to be the first letters instead of the second letters:
`AB`

Is there any way that I can do it without using reverse function?

Comment: Sets are unordered. If you need the items in some specific order *but without duplicates*, then you can convert the set back into a list, sort that and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets in Python are still unordered unfortunately. However, `dictionaries` in newer versions of Python already [preserve insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6).

You can take advantage of this, by defining a `dictionary` with empty values, such that you can extract the `keys` in insertion order:

```
x = 'ABBA'
x = "".join({k:None for k in x}.keys())
print(x)
# AB
```

The idea is a bit hacky, but it works for now. Maybe in the future sets will also respect insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are [`unordered`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/). so try this.

```
from collections import Counter


x = 'ABBA'

x = "".join(Counter(x).keys())

print(x) # AB
```